# JavaScript Loops With If and Else

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

how come the following is not accurately logging whether a number is prime or not?

```
function isPrime2(num) {    
for(let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
if(num % i === 0) {
return console.log(false); break;
} else{return console.log(true)}
}
}
```

isPrime2(33)returns true, even though it is a prime number.

If i = 2, then the console will log true since 33/2 = 16.5
But since the loop isn't over, the next i value is i=3,
so shouldn't the console log false and then break out of the loop completely, leaving the final answer to be false?

Comment: 33 is not a prime number.

Comment: `return console.log(false)` is not the way to return `false`. You should: `console.log(false); return false;`. No need to `break` since `return false` will have the same effect. Same thing with `return console.log(true)`. Try `console.log(true); return true;`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

## Your logic is broken

```js
function isPrime2(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    const remainder = num % i;
    console.log({
      remainder
    });
    if (remainder === 0) {
      return console.log(false);
      break;
    } else {
      return console.log(true)
    }
  }
}

isPrime2(33);
```

`i` starts at `2`.

`if(num % i === 0)` is false, so we go to `else`

`else{return console.log(true)}` causes it to log `true` and exit the function.

---

Your failure condition is triggered when the *first* test fails instead of waiting for the loop to finish with a success condition for *any* of the tests.

---

## 33 is not a prime

It is divisible by `3` and `11`.

```js
function isPrime2(num) {
  for (let i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    const remainder = num % i;
    console.log({
      remainder
    });
    if (remainder === 0) {
      return console.log(false);
      break;
    }
  }
  return console.log(true)
}

isPrime2(33);
```